# What is the best practice to initialize an empty list in python ([] or list())?

Tags: python, list, initialization, empty-list

I'm new to python and I've seen two different ways to initialize an empty list:

```
# way 1    
empty_list = []

# way 2
other_empty_list = list()
```

Is there a "preferred" way to do it? Maybe one way is better for certain conditions than the other?

Thank you

Comment: `[]` is the Pythonic way

Comment: Hello and welcome Dan.py. It seems like this issue has been answered but if you are unfamiliar with "list comprehension" I would recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` is the pythonic way.
`[]` way is quite efficient as you can see from below image.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

No there isn't much of a difference, you can neglect the difference and pick anyone of them

As most of the times it's a one or limited execution any difference in execution won't have much impact

Answer (score -3):

Using parenthesis will create a tuple, which is immutable. A list uses brackets.

Comment: This is wrong. Both statements result in list.

Comment: Not according to my textbook on python.

Comment: Just run this statement in your compliler: `type(list()) == type([])` and will get `True`.

Comment: I checked and what actually creates a tupple is the , not the ()